# How to see annotations

Tags: rust, rust-crates

In `https://docs.rs/[package]/...`, the RHS lists objects like "Modules, Macros, ...". However, how do you see what annotations it exposes?

As a helpful example—this is not the whole question, just an example—`serde_json` claims to expose only the `json` macro. However, I know that there are additional macros you can use to annotate struct fields (like "rename"). I clicked into all of the submodules and I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you refer to as "annotations" are in fact called "attributes". They are not their own thing but tied to the derive proc macro. Hence they do not appear in the automatically generated documentation and they have to be either read from the source of the proc macro implementation, or they need to be documented by hand. This section in the Rust Reference explains helper attributes for derive macros: [Derive macro helper attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#derive-macro-helper-attributes)

As for the example of the `serde` crate family, the derive macro for the `Serialize`/`Deserialize` traits are actually defined by the `serde_derive` crate and the associated attributes are not JSON-specific. The documentation link for [`serde_derive` on crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/serde_derive) in fact links to a [hand-written documentation](https://serde.rs/derive.html) which [explains the intended usage of the attributes](https://serde.rs/attributes.html) in detail.